# .dropna() doesn't remove all NaN from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a code in which i filter out some stopwords and special characters. The dropna() filters out most of the existing NaN but the `cleaner = clean.str.replace('#|\|_|!|.|\^|:|(|)|-|\?|!|\,','')`  line creates some new NaN in the csv file (some lines are just special chars), these aren't filtered out. How can i filter these out as well?

```
import pandas as pd
from stop_words  import get_stop_words

df = pd.read_csv("F:/textclustering/data/cleandata.csv", encoding="iso-8859-1")

usertext = df[df.Role.str.contains("End-user",na=False)][['Data','chatid']]
lowertext = usertext['Data'].map(lambda x: x if type(x)!=str else x.lower())

nl_stop_words = get_stop_words('dutch')
stop_words_pat = '|'.join(['\\b' + stop +  '\\b' for stop in nl_stop_words])
clean = lowertext.str.replace(stop_words_pat, '')
cleaner = clean.str.replace('\#|\|\_|\!|\.|\^|\:|\(|\)|\-|\?|\!|\,','')

render = pd.concat([cleaner, usertext['chatid']], axis=1)
#print(render)
#print(type(render))

final= render.dropna(how='any')

final.to_csv("F:/textclustering/data/filteredtext.csv", sep=',',index=False, encoding="iso-8859-1")

df2 = pd.read_csv("F:/textclustering/data/filteredtext.csv", encoding="iso-8859-1")

print(df2)
```

UPDATE: Raw Data

```
"Agent","Chat.Event","Role","Data","chatid"
Chat ID: ^^^^^^,,,"",1
x,Agent Accepted,Lead,"Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur",1
x,Engagement Participant Entered,Lead,,1
No Value,End-user Post,End-user,"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus",1
x,Agent Post,Lead,"Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",1
No Value,End-user Post,End-user,"Et harum quidem rerum!",1
x,Agent Post,Lead,"omnis voluptas assumenda est",1
No Value,End-user Post,End-user,"assumenda est",1
x,Agent Post,Lead,"Nam libero tempore?",1
x,Agent Post,Lead,"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",1
x,Agent Post,Lead,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed?",1
No Value,End-user Post,End-user,"^^########",1
```

(i have replaced the dutch text for lorum impsum for privacy reasons)
The last Line stays NaN

Comment: Post raw data that reproduces your issue

Comment: replace `''` created by the cleaner replace with nan `final= final.replace('', nan)` and then dropna `final.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)`?

Comment: I tried that before, but then i get TypeError: repl must be a string

Comment: Tried it again and it works, but i still have some other NaN's that appear, this time it seams because of the stopword removal.

Comment: Thanks for the help :), got the full filter code working now!!